# Uses of .sub() in real life

Tags: jquery

I stumbled upon the `.sub` function from browsing the jQuery source. There is a [documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.sub/) but it doesn't show any convincing 'real-life' applications.

Do people actually use `.sub()`? If so, for what?

Comment: If you'll need it, you'd be glad it's there ;)

Comment: All of the examples there look convincing. It's just that you don't need to go into that territory unless you are a plugin writer. Which most people are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine having two public plugins with the same name but different functionality. Using jquery.sub() you can load both of them.